# AngularJS nested ng-repeat access to Index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have nested array so I had to use 3 times ng-repeat

```
    <div ng-repeat = "cat in cats"  >

          <div ng-repeat = "kitty in cat  "  >

             <button ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button>

      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

So my problem is that I can't get access to 2nd ng-repeat $index , any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the purpose of the [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-init="catIndex = $index">
   <div ng-repeat="kitty in cat">
        <button ng-click="delete(catIndex)">Delete</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively use `(index, value)` formatting:

```
<div ng-repeat="(catIndex, cat) in cats">
   <div ng-repeat="kitty in cat">
        <button ng-click="delete(catIndex)">Delete</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or you could have used the (key, value) ng-repeat syntax?

Comment: @ryeballar - that's for objects, not arrays

Comment: You're wrong, it works for arrays as well. If the element being iterated in an `ng-repeat` is an array then the `key` is the index. Thus, you can do it like this, `ng-repeat="(catIndex, cat) in cats"`

Comment: You can add an update to your answer, at least the OP is aware of his options, you answer is correct but it adds `N` more times the watchers.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div ng-repeat = "cat in cats track by $catIndex"  >

          <div ng-repeat = "kitty in cat track by $kittyIndex "  >

             <button ng-click="delete($kittyIndex)">Delete</button>

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `track by` has nothing to do with $index